# PGI 18.1 vs PGI 18.4

Tags: gpu, pgi, pgi-accelerator

Is there any change from the PGi version 18.1 to 18.4 regarding the 
#pragma routine seq, the code I have works fine with version 18.1 but gives an error when I use the newer version. I generate kernels using the math library.

using namespace std;
    #pragma acc routine
    double myfunc(double x)
    {
    return(fabs(x));
    }

The default parallelism for routine directive is (or was) sequential.
i.e.  #pragma acc routine is equivalent to #pragma acc routine seq

This works fine in version 18.1. 
But I think there might be some change in the new version since when  I compile with 18.4 version, it gives an error complaining about the math library function.

Oddly enough  also causes error

#include cmath

#include "openacc.h"

using namespace std;

```
#pragma acc routine seq
double sine( double x )
{
    return ( sin( x ) );
}
```

Gives compilation error but when I change the math library to math.h, it is perfectly fine, Can anyone explain why  is not working with pgc++ ?

Answer (score 1):

What's the actual error you get?  I get the same error with both PGI 18.1 and 18.4:

```
% pgc++ -c test1.cpp -ta=tesla -Minfo=accel -w -V18.1
PGCC-S-1000-Call in OpenACC region to procedure 'sin' which has no acc routine information (test1.cpp: 10)
PGCC-S-0155-Compiler failed to translate accelerator region (see -Minfo messages)  (test1.cpp: 10)
sine(double):
     10, Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
         11, Accelerator restriction: call to 'sin' with no acc routine information
```

The solution here is to include the PGI header "accelmath.h" to get the device version for the C99 math intrinsics.

```
% diff test1.cpp test2.cpp
4a5
> #include "accelmath.h"
% pgc++ -c test2.cpp -ta=tesla -Minfo=accel -w -V18.1
sine(double):
     12, Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
% pgc++ -c test2.cpp -ta=tesla -Minfo=accel -w -V18.4
sine(double):
     12, Generating acc routine seq
         Generating Tesla code
```

Comment: Hi Mat, thanks for the information,  I will make that change, however, if you change <cmath> to <math.h> it works, is this due to scope difference bewteen <cmath> and <math.h>

Comment: Yes, it because there only device routines for the C99 math intrinsics.

Comment: Mat, I have a rather large code that I can not share on here, I get into issues when I enable -O3 optimization, with -O1 it compiles without error, can  I sen  this code to you, it has a cmake and set up regenerate the error easily. Thanks

Comment: Please send a note to PGI Customer Support (trs@pgroup.com) or submit a problem report at https://www.pgroup.com/support/support_request.php I'm a bit swamped with prep for SC19 but if I don't have time to take a look, I can ask someone else here to help.